# Android - Material Design - NavigationView - How to put vertical scroll?

Tags: android, scrollview, material-design, navigationview

i'm using NavigationView with `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'`
Well, everything is good unless it hasn't vertical scroll
How do I set it via xml?

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <foo>
    </foo>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        style="@style/NavigationViewTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I believe it is not possible.

Comment: Gmail and other apps has vertical scroll on menu drawer

Comment: Maybe they are not using NavigationView, which is quite recent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this, it seems to be a bug on design library. Updating the library solved my problem

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your activity java file

```
navigationView.bringToFront();
navigationView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` in `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`

Comment: Nothing happen, is missing anything else?

Comment: @DouglasFornaro try to put your menu in a scroll view