# scrollView not working on android

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm using ScrollView in one of my layout files that contains my drawer navigation items. this file is included in Main_Activity.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/drawer_item_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/drawer_item_padding"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/drawer_item_text_size"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_love"
        android:text="@string/fav_words"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_item"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/drawer_item_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/drawer_item_padding"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/drawer_item_text_size"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_love"
        android:text="@string/fav_words"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

        <!-- and many other textViews here -->


</LinearLayout>
```

but scrollView doesn't work. I already have read other topics about this problem and no one solved my problem.

"scrollView not working " means I can't use the benefit of scrollView that shows it's inside content by scrolling!

Activity_Main :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/toolbar_background"
tools:openDrawer="end"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    tools:openDrawer="end">
    <include layout="@layout/navigation_view"></include>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ir.cupcode.vazhename.MainActivity">
<include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@color/toolbar_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_border"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "scrollView doesnot work" - is insufficient try to explain..what is the actual problem..

Comment: could you post the full axml? Is there anything else beyond </LinearLayout> or just </Scrollview>?

Comment: @fmaccaroni no there is not. this file is included in my Main_Activity

Comment: if there is no other layout/widget in this file ... **YOUR SCROLLVIEW IS NOT SUPPOSED TO SCROLL**

Comment: @SantanuSur Excause me, Does textView is being counted as Layout?:-D if yes so there is more textView in this file and I just removed them to submit this topic.

Comment: check the updated comment @cupcode

Comment: @SantanuSur thank you, I edited my code. yes there is more textViews there

Comment: **this file is included in my Main_Activity.xml** please post your main_activity

Comment: @SantanuSur added.

Comment: take the scrollView layout outside the navigatuionView layout..

Comment: @SantanuSur didn't get that.

Comment: `<include layout="@layout/navigation_view"></include>` put it above `navigationView`

Comment: @SantanuSur now my navigation drawer is gone!

Comment: is the scroll view working now ??

Comment: Have you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32289117/6248510

Comment: @fmaccaroni I'm using the latest one.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_principal_menu"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
android:elevation="6dp"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
```

put your content you wanna display after the code above, and finish the xml file with the code below

```
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Ps: The layout may be the layout of your choice, but I recommend using LinearLayout for this type of scroll, makes understanding easier

Comment: is that the entire xml of yours?

Comment: I'll edit my answer with an example that is working on my code, maybe you can get something out of it